# ForkIO with a stateT

Tags: haskell

How can we make a user pass an eventHandler, which uses a stateMonad but is invoked in a separate thread? For example the in the following example, how should the forkIO be called so that eventHandler can invoke operate? I am new to Haskell, please correct me if this is a wrong api to expose to users?

```
data MyTypeResult a = MyTypeValue a
data MyTypeState = MyTypeState {_counter :: Int}

newtype MyType a = MyType {
      unMyType :: StateT MyTypeState IO (MyTypeResult a)
}

instance Monad MyType where
    (>>=) = myTypeBind
    return = myTypeReturn
    fail = myTypeFail

myTypeBind = undefined
myTypeReturn = undefined
myTypeFail = undefined

type Event = String
type Handler =  Event -> MyType ()

doSomethingAwesome :: MyType Event
doSomethingAwesome = undefined

operate :: String -> MyType ()
operate = undefined

start :: Handler -> MyType ()
start h = do
  event <- doSomethingAwesome
  --forkIO $ h event -- The line that is troubling
  return ()

testHandler :: Event -> MyType()
testHandler _ = operate "abcd"

myMain = start testHandler
```

Comment: Are you going to be forking many of these state computations?  Will each of these forked computations share the same state?

Comment: Yes, I plan to fork and call the handler a lot of times. Yes the forked computations will share the same state (the part of state that will be used in these computations is thread safe)

Comment: What is the initial state you intend to give the handler? You need to provide an initial state in order to run a 'StateT' computation using 'runStateT' or 'evalStateT'.

Comment: @DanielDíazCarrete You are correct. My mistake (and hopefully now fixed). The handler is being called inside the MyType monad (which is why the forkIO is not working)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot have a `State` computation running in multiple threads sharing the same state because behind the scenes, the `State` monad is nothing more than a chain of function calls that passes the state value on to the next function in the chain.

For multithreaded code you can replace `StateT s IO` with `ReaderT (IORef s) IO` and use

```
forkIO $ runReaderT (h event) stateVar
```

to fork new threads (where `stateVar` is an `IORef` that contains the shared state).

Inside the `ReaderT` stack, you read the current shared state with

```
stateVar <- ask
s <- lift $ readIORef stateVar
```

and update it with

```
stateVar <- ask
lift $ atomicModifyIORef stateVar f
```

where `f` is a pure function that takes the current state and returns the modified state plus an auxiliary result.

If you need anything more fancy (e.g. modify the state using monadic functions), then you should use either `MVar` or `TVar` instead of `IORef`.

Comment: This is a very interesting solutions. Will try it out.

Answer (score 2):

While it's true you cannot have multiple `StateT s IO` actions running in multiple threads, all sharing the same `s` state, you can have a `StateT s IO` running in a thread with its state in isolation from others using `monad-control` and `lifted-base`.

I recently stumbled on these packages, it's quite amazing. Heres a simple example

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import Control.Concurrent.Lifted
import Control.Monad.Base
import Control.Monad.Trans.Control
import Control.Monad.State

t :: IO Int -> StateT Int IO ()
t io = replicateM_ 10 $ do
    x <- get
    y <- liftIO io
    liftIO $ print x
    put $ x + y

async :: MonadBaseControl IO m => (IO a -> m ()) -> m (a -> IO ())
async thread = do
    mvar <- liftBase newEmptyMVar
    fork $ thread (takeMVar mvar)
    return $ liftBase . putMVar mvar

main :: IO ()
main = evalStateT (async t) 0 >>= forM_ [1..10]
```

Basically, as long as your monad is a transformer stack over `IO`, you can fork, handle exceptions or any other `IO` specific actions "inside" your transformer stack.

Answer (score 0):

`forkIO` won't work from inside `MyType` until you use `liftIO` by implementing MonadIO class for MyType OR you can make MyType just a type synonym and do:

```
data MyTypeResult a = MyTypeValue a
data MyTypeState = MyTypeState {_counter :: Int}

type MyType a = StateT MyTypeState IO (MyTypeResult a)

type Event = String
type Handler =  Event -> MyType ()

doSomethingAwesome :: MyType Event
doSomethingAwesome = undefined

operate :: String -> MyType ()
operate = undefined

start :: Handler -> MyType ()
start h = do
    MyTypeValue event <- doSomethingAwesome
    st <- get
    liftIO $ forkIO $ runStateT (h event) st >> (return ())
    return $ MyTypeValue ()

testHandler :: Event -> MyType()
testHandler _ = operate "abcd"

myMain = start testHandler
```